# Duplicate fields in the same table with different values

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursor

I'm trying to create a stored procedure that allow me to duplicate some specific tuples on the same table but with different values. I have already a stored procedure that allow me to create a tuple of SOCIETE Table with all the fields :

```
 FUNCTION createPerson(P_ID_SOCIETE_PERE SOCIETE.ID_SOCIETE_PERE%TYPE
            , P_SOURCE_SOCIETE_PERE SOCIETE.SOURCE_SOCIETE_PERE%TYPE
            ,......)
```

Now I have to use it to duplicate persons on the the same table, changing just a single field, for example "field3 = 'N' " where this condition is satisfied for exemple :

```
select s.ID_SOCIETE , s.SOURCE_SOCIETE
  , s.RAISON_SOCIALE
from FACTURE f, SOCIETE s, partenaire p
where  s.ID_SOCIETE = f.SOC_ID and s.SOURCE_SOCIETE = f.SOC_SOURCE
and p.ID_SOCIETE = f.SOC_ID
group by s.SOURCE_SOCIETE , s.SOURCE_SOCIETE
  , s.RAISON_SOCIALE ;
```

To do so, I was told to use Oracle PL/SQL cursors. Someone have an easy example to follow please ?
If i suppose I need to duplicate all ID greater than 490, changing the SOURCE_SOCIETE to 'B' instead of 'A' before recopying it to the same table, how could I do it with cursors ??

[image]

Comment: Please post some sample data and needed result to clarify your question

Comment: Can't you just select the column that needs to be same and hardcode the ones that needs to be changed and feed it to insert?

Comment: Problem is there is a lot real lot of tuples data, and i was told i need to do it with a stored procedure using Oracle Cursor ...

Comment: That's fine too. Come up with the query, use it to define the cursor and process cursor output in form of batches using `BULK COLLECT`

Comment: @GurwinderSingh thank you for your comment, but what i'm trying to do something a little bit different, i'm tryng to fetch all the fields i'm getting into the function parameter, so it can insert directly and auto generate the ID, something like : **FETCH CURSOR INTO exec myProcedure(.." here"...)**

Comment: Is this a homework and the teacher did tell you that you **must** use a cursor ? If not, then use simple `INSERT .... SELECT ....` in your procedure instead of cursors, it's the easiest way, doing that using cursors is cumbersome.

Comment: @krokodilko - if there are multiple transformations then `INSERT .... SELECT .... ` might not be "simple".

Comment: @APC 10 you are absolutery right, but @Anna wrote `changing just a single field, for example "field3 = 'N' `, it appears to be only single transformation, not multiple.

Comment: I read "for example" to mean that any individual column could be changed. Or indeed any combination of columns. I think my proposed solution would make that easier to implement than writing a dynamic `INSERT .... SELECT ....  ` statement.

Answer (score 0):

> "i was told i need to do it with a stored procedure using Oracle Cursor"

Well, you could always ask the person who told you that instead of a bunch of strangers on the internet, but anyway..

Here is the sort of thing I think they had in mind. (Untested code, so watch out for syntax errors and bugs).

```
create or replace procedure duplicate_records
   ( p_in_recs in sys_refcursor
     , p_rec_count out pls_integer )
is
    type SOCIETE_array is table of SOCIETE%rowtype;
    dup_recs SOCIETE_array;
    dup_count simple_integer := 0;
begin
    loop
        fetch p_in_recs bulk collect into dup_recs limit 100;
        exit when dup_recs.count() = 0;
        for idx in 1..dup_recs.count() loop
            dup_recs(idx).SOURCE_SOCIETE = 'B';
            -- dup_recs(idx).ID := ?????
        end loop;
        forall j in 1..dup_recs.count()
            insert into SOCIETE
            values dup_recs(j);
        dup_count := dup_count + sql%rowcount;
    end loop;
    p_rec_count := dup_count;
end;
/
```

You would call it like this:

```
declare
    n pls_integer;
begin
    duplicate_records ( cursor (select * from societe where id > 490 )
                         , n );
end ;
/
```

Few points to note:

- it would be better to declare `p_in_recs` as a hard cursor defined against SOCIETE table. Do this if you're writing a package.
- I have hard-coded the transformation in the inner loop. This is a massive cheat. Probably you'll need to implement a lot of complex rules for the update.
- I have ignored the updating of ID. You'll need to handle that (unless it's done automatically in a trigger